# JsonConvert not working in PCL in Xamarin iOS App

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, json.net, portable-class-library

I tried to serialize a simple object inside the PCL it just returns a `"{}"` string. However, it does not throw any exceptions.

```
var test = new
{
    Email = email,
    Password = password,
    Username = username
};
var testJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

When I inspect the `JsonConvert`object inside the VS debugger it says that the method `SerializeObject` is an unknown member. Furthermore, when I inspect the DeserializeMethod, it says:

`Could not resolve type: global::Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DefaultResponse>`

Both methods are displayed as variables inside the debugger.

Comment: if this is a Forms project, you need to install the Newtonsoft package in both the PCL and platform projects

Comment: @Jason It's an iOS storyboard project.

Comment: regardless, do you have the package installed in both the iOS project and the PCL project?

Comment: Yes, it is installed in both projected. I even tried to install it via Nuget and the component store and it did not work.

Comment: @Jason In addition, it also doesn't work inside the iOS project.